# Where does uWSGI put its profiler file?

Tags: python, uwsgi, cprofile

I'm using uWSGI with the "--profiler" flag switched on but I can't seem to find the output file (if there is one), and (like many things in uWSGI) this isn't properly documented.

Comment: Looks like profiler reports are getting [logged](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/master/plugins/python/profiler.c#L36)

Comment: @dhke Thanks but I don't see any of those prints there. If it's using cProfile it should output a binary file, doesn't it?

Comment: There's no reference to `cProfile` anywhere in uwsgi'S source. From  what I can deduce, `--profiler=pycall` and `--profiler=pyline` are supported. Specifying a different argument seems to be [silently ignored](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/3e5493259eac999a5b347bbd695a3d2e441dc496/plugins/python/python_plugin.c#L1233).

Comment: Thank you. You're right both times. Unfortunately this isn't the kind of profiling I've been looking for :( No memory related info there

Comment: Were you able to get any further on this? A possible workaround for running python with cprofile under uWSGI?

Comment: @jab sorry dude, pretty much dropped it at that point

Answer (score 0):

A useful trick is to use *uWSGI*s logger to filter out the profiler logs into their own file:

```
uwsgi \
    << other uwsgi options >> \
    --logger profiler file:/path/to/profile.log \
    --log-route profiler uWSGI Python profiler
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got this problem today. Here is a good project, you can use: https://github.com/what-studio/profiling

I used it from my code, like this:

```
from profiling.tracing import TracingProfiler

profiler = TracingProfiler()
profiler.start()
# ... run your program...
profiler.stop()
# save profile data to file
profiler.dump('path/to/file')
```